# Maven: how to pass profile argument down to submodules in POM

Tags: maven

I inherited a code base from a colleague and I am looking at optimising some things.

1) One of the issues is that he generates some codes using a WSDL which is fine on itself.
However what is not is that he has a dev, test and prod folder which contain the actual module with only the WSDL files differing. Now the first thing that popped up in my mind is to create one module and just add 3 profiles which contains the configuration for the `cxf-codegen-plugin` plugin.

2) However this brings up an additional issue that I would like to fix, currently he first build the submodule so it is installed to the .m2 repository, and then builds the rest using a root pom (which does not define the WSDL module as a module so it is not build). I would like to fix it, so that when I do a clean install on the root pom the actual classes are also generated again. However I am not quite certain how to accomplish this and I couldn't really find a way to achieve this.

3) Or would you just resolve issue 1, and skip 2?

Comment: I think I missed the relation between your question title and the actual question

Comment: If there is a way I can just do mvn clean install -Pprod and have it passed down to the WSDL module so it knows which WSDL file to use for the cxf-codegen plugin based on there being a dev\tst\prod profile in that module.